# Illusion of joined input fields

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to recreate the bootstrap look of input fields whereby they look joined together in one box like this:

[image]

Can anyone give me a hand with the CSS used to create this effect?

HTML:

```
<div>
   <input type='text' placeholder='email' />
   <input type='text' placeholder='password' />
</div>
```

Comment: try padding-bottom for each element.

Comment: please show your html as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you can set border-radius individually, so:

```
.joined input{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:   none;
   appearance:        none;
   border:1px solid;
   display:block;
   margin:0;
   padding:4px;
}

.joined input:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.joined input:nth-child(2) {
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  border-top: none;
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2nc9j/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options, but in general you have to play with margins, borders and border radius. For example:

Html:

```
<div>
   <input type=text class="topInput">
   <input type=text class="bottomInput">
</div>
```

Css:

```
input{
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    line-height:0px;
    border:1px solid gray;
}

input.topInput{
    border-radius:4px 4px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom:none;
}

input.bottomInput{
    border-radius:0px 0px 4px 4px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/AhK7D/